# results from query using multiplication is not same?

Tags: mysql

I couldn't get the results I expected using my query, and I don't know why. Can you help me and explain it to me?
so basically I only run standard queries like this:

```
SELECT a.bimbel_kode,c.kriteria_kode,d.pencarian_kode, b.osk_val,d.bsk_val,
        ((d.bsk_val/100)*b.osk_val) as total
FROM bimbel_sub a 
    INNER JOIN opsi_sub_kriteria b ON a.osk_id=b.osk_id
    INNER JOIN sub_kriteria c on b.sk_id=c.sk_id
    INNER JOIN bobot_sub_kriteria d ON c.sk_id=d.sk_id
WHERE d.pencarian_kode='KDS7808b075'
```

and in total, I could not get the results I wanted.

this is the result that I got from my query
[image]

```
for the total must be like this
total = (bsk_val/100) * osk_val
total = 50/100 * 4
total = 2
But why my reults be 0.12 ?
```

this my fiddle [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80a6ff/5)

Comment: Check the datatype of `bobot_sub_kriteria.bsk_val` its an ENUM maybe it should be a float or decimal

Comment: yes i use enum as data type, do i have to convert it to float?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is because you're using an ENUM. When casting an ENUM to an integer you get it's sequence not it's value(so 100 is 1, 75 is 2, 50 is 3, 25 is 4, etc).

If you want to avoid this issue you should cast it to a varchar/char and then cast it back:

```
CAST(CAST(d.bsk_val AS CHAR) AS SIGNED) / 100 * b.osk_val
```

Comment: ok thank you this works fine, so i don't need to change it to integer?

Comment: I think if you're doing maths on it then you should probably make it a numerical type, but really you should use the type that best represents the data you're storing and if discrete 25 increments best represents what you're storing go for it, just be aware of the consequences if you try to use it as a number again